# How change the format of full calendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar

I want to change the format of date which is showing on text box after choosing dates. I tried format table and other coding found in Google but it doesn't work.

```
<form action="report_emp.php" method="post">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>From</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="date01">Date</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge datepicker" id="date01" name="datefrom" value="mm/dd/yy">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>To</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="date02">Date</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="input-xlarge datepicker" id="date02" name="dateto" value="mm/dd/yy">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Find Client Details</button>
        <button class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what kind of foimat ? are you adding datepicker of jquery ui ? or bootsrap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about jquery datepicker, then you can use:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm/dd/yy" );
```

[Check here.](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)